# Sending invitation emails WSO2 EMM fails

Tags: email, smtp, wso2

I'm trying out the WSO2 Enterprise Mobile Manager but I can't seem to get it configured right.

If I want to send an invitation e-mail to a user, my SMTP-server doesn't accept the given recipient address. Apparently the EMM formats an address with surrounding quotes like this:

```
RCPT TO: <"user@example.com">
```

And if I try it manually like this, I have no problem:

```
RCPT TO: <user@example.com>
```

Is there a setting I can configure in the EMM-software or on my SMTP-server (MailEnable for testing purposes) (or the Carbon/EMM source code on GitHub) to fix this ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have followed the step 10 of [getting started document](https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/General+Server+Configurations). This email component is derived through [Jaggery](http://jaggeryjs.org/) where it has been used in multiple products as well as it has been tested on multiple SMPT servers. Then I believe you have to configure or setup this from your SMTP server side if you believe that the issue is with that double quotes.