# Emails sent by WSO2 EMM has double quotes in the RCPT TO recipient

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I can send messages and receive messages sent by EMM , but the email clients like outlook and gmail show email recipient like this, appending the mail server hostname

```
Mail to: user@example.com@mailserver.example.com
```

If I examine the message, I can see that wso2 put double quotes in email address. I think that this is the cause of my probloem.

```
RCPT TO: <"user@example.com">
```

How can  I configure EMM to send emails without quotes?

```
RCPT TO: <user@example.com>
```

Comment: This has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630458/sending-invitation-emails-wso2-emm-fails/22642528#22642528